# how to embed gecko in windows form application c#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

hello i am beginner in c#/.net and i don't know how to add extra control's in  visual studio 2008.

i want to know that how can i use Gecko rather then webBrowsercontrol.

i have downloaded Gecko wrapper but i don't know how to use this browser in c#/.net. please tell me how can i use Gecko in c#/.net windows form application as we use webBrowser control.
i have tried to add this control in visual studio toolbox but i didn't get success..........................................................................

Answer (score 0):

You right click on the toolbox, tou must select "Choose Items.." and select to the dll containing the control Gecko

Comment: i have added geckowebbrowser but when i try to run my application i got this error "XULRunner not fount" what is this thing and is this ting is required in other system to run my application

Comment: is a software which allows you to launch applications XUL, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Getting_started_with_XULRunner